# Removing features from android OS

Tags: android

I want to customize the android OS for my specific needs.What i want to do exactly is eg:-
remove the access to android market, remove contacts, calendar.etc.

basically I want to have apps that I permit.
Even if removing the icon is all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do so you will have create a new custom ROM and only you will be able to install...

Not every one would prefer to install without default features like Market etc..

Comment: True, but he is probably developing this for a specific client

Comment: @Lucas B: Yeah, What I want to do is I want the user to have access only to 2-3 specific apps.And access to the web.All other stuff must be disabled, and I want to enforce permissions so that the user may not change the phone settings, eg: adjust the date.